# Title bar settings missing in GNOME Tweaks on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool, titlebar, window-buttons

I tried to move my "close, minimise and maximise" to the right + add the macOS theme to it. However, I have not been able to find any settings for that. In *GNOME Tweaks* > *Windows* the settings to put the buttons to the right are missing completely.

[image: Tweaks Settings]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the GNOME Tweaks window look under '**Window Titlebars**' section, instead of '*Windows*' section:
[image]

You can also achieve your goal simply using the command-line. To move the window buttons to the right, launch Terminal and just run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```